# Zip file compression failed “output file write failure, your disk could be full” even though I have enough space

Tags: compression, zip, storage

I want to compress a 45 gb file with zip, but it says “output file write failure, your disk could be full” after about 20 minutes. I have another 4 terabytes of storage left.

Comment: Which tool are you using to create the archive? How are you doing it, exactly? You have 4 TB of free space where?

Comment: @gronostaj I’m using the default windows zip tool, the process is right click>send to>zip file. The 4 tb of space is on an external hard drive, which is where the original file is

Comment: IIRC the built-in ZIP feature stores the temporary file in user's temp directory, usually on the C: drive. Try a different program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip is limited to 4 GiB of data. It was designed this way (32 bits). Over 4 GiB of archive data unknown problems may appear. It was changed later in other types of zip programs, but you may be using the older one which has limitations.

It would be better to use gzip or other archive formats like 7-Zip or RAR to fix the problem.

Or you can try to change type of zip format used by options in the command line. There is zip-64 which should work.